# Variable scope in javascript when iterating through a stack

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm baffled. Could someone please explain to me why this produces an infinite loop?

```
var constant = 4;
var stack = new Array();
stack.push(0);
stack.push(1);
loop1();


function loop1(){    
    for(i = 0; i < constant; i++){
        loop2(i);
    }
}

function loop2(num){
    for(i = 0; i < stack.length; i++){
        console.log(i); 
    }
}
```

​
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/tywV9

I suspect it has something to do with Javascript function-level variable scope, but that's as far as my guess goes.

Comment: I think your problem is that you're not declaring `i`, try `var i = 0` in your loops

Comment: We don't normally have to declare variable in JS, do we? Why must we in this case then?

Comment: If you don't then `i` is global and can cause problems.

Comment: @LimH You *should* declare variables with the `var` keyword because otherwise they are implicitly made global variables. For a whole host of reasons, limiting the use of global variables is strongly encouraged.

Comment: Plus the fiddle with global `i` hangs on my browser while with `var` it doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/UEjaY/

Comment: Thank you for your response. The first snippet was written incorrectly when I tried to extract it out of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't declare a variable with the `var` keyword, the variable is global, so `loop2` and `loop1` are using the same (global) `i` variable. Every time `loop2` is called, `i` gets set to 0 and then is incremented up to `stack.length`, which is 2. This means that every iteration of `loop1` will end with `i=2`, which gets incremented to 3 but never reaches `constant` which is 4.

If you change your for loops to be `for (var i = 0; ...)` instead of `for (i = 0; ...)` then this should no longer loop infinitely.